# arm caches flush to uncached region

Tags: operating-system, arm, embedded, cpu-cache, cortex-a8

I wondering how the cache subsystem will act in the following situation:
Let's consider Cortex-a8 and VIPT L1-cache.
Suppose a cacheable virtual memory mapping [A,B] was created, for some time the one worked with this memory region so the data cache was filled up. After this, suppose, the mapping [A,B] was substituted by uncacheable. After that we perform a flush operation (DCCIMVAC) on virtual region [A,B]. What will happen in this situation? The cache data will be just discarded (invalidated)? Or data will be flushed to non cacheable pages anyway? Or something else?

---

Update:

The main reason why I'am asking is - my board stucks immediately after one of this flush instructions in the context I described above. I just have no idea why this could happen. More literally, it hangs in the middle of the page, flushing one of the cache lines at the offset 0xd80. If skip this cache line flush - it goes further. If change attrs to cacheable (from uncacheable) it works ok. And looks like it should be changed to cacheable, but I try to figure out what this code had done. I'am mostly interested in - if the scenario I had described is legal, or it may lead to some undefined behavior.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: the flush commands should go directly to the cache control registers and the cache should respond.  marking the region as uncacheable, I assume you mean mmu, just means the amba/axi transactions dont show cacheable but still happen.  I don tthink arm uses the term flush, but that tends to mean write the stuff out to memory, where invalidate means discard.  arm uses terms like clean, although that may vary from document to document.

Comment: just try it....

Comment: what do you mean by uncached?  an mmu setting?

Comment: I mean mmu settings. I have added more context (see update)

Comment: To me, it sounds more like the program is going haywire because you are fiddling with the MMU "live". I wouldn't touch it while any high level language code is executing.

Comment: You should flush or invalidate the cache range when you change the MMU properties from cached to uncached depending on your use case.  Also you need to flush the TLB.  Have you coded things yourself or are you using some OS?

Comment: the mmu and the cache should be separate and mmus have to work live, the operating system being used to read this page relies on it.  But at the same time there are rules and procedures for synchronization before simply taking away the cache such that the program using the data now gets old/state data from ram rather than the fresh data in cache.